python logger init to `level=20` (INFO) do not show debug if I later change to `level=10` (DEBUG)
I changed my logging default level to logging.INFO (20) from Logging.DEBUG (10), but then it wont show debug messages if I change logLevel to 'DEBUG' later on in the code:
Old config works fine:
>>> import mylog
>>> log1 = mylog.mylogger('log1',level=10) # default is DEBUG
added logger log1 of level:10
>>> log1
<Logger log1 (DEBUG)>
>>> log1.debug("works")
20241007163742.800|DEBUG|<stdin>:1|works
>>> log1.setLevel(20)
>>> log1
<Logger log1 (INFO)>
>>> log1.info("works")
20241007163825.042|INFO|<stdin>:1|works
>>> log1.debug("should not show") 
>>> 

I can also go back to debug and it works:
>>> log1.setLevel(10)
>>> log1
<Logger log1 (DEBUG)>
>>> log1.debug("works")
20241007164010.113|DEBUG|<stdin>:1|works

All fine, except default logging is DEBUG which logs a bit too much if I do not change the loglevel.
But if I defaults to level=20 I can't see DEBUG after a log2.setLevel(10):
>>> log2 = mylog.mylogger('log2',level=20) # default is INFO
added logger log2 of level:20
>>> log2
<Logger log2 (INFO)>
>>> log2.info("works")
20241007164505.921|INFO|<stdin>:1|works
>>> log2.debug("should not show") 
>>> log2.setLevel(10)
>>> log2
<Logger log2 (DEBUG)>
>>> log2.info("works as before")
20241007164628.199|INFO|<stdin>:1|works as before
>>> log2.debug("why is this not showing")
>>> 

my simplified log module mylog.py:
import logging
def mylogger(name:str, level:int=logging.INFO) -> logging.Logger:
    """ default logger """
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    if logger.hasHandlers():
        print(f"logger {name} already has handler")
    else:
        logger.setLevel(level)
        console_fmt = "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d|%(levelname)s|%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d|%(message)s"
        datefmt = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(level)
        ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(file_fmt, datefmt))
        logger.addHandler(ch)
        logger.propagate = False
        print(f"added logger {name} of level:{logger.level}")
    return logger

Could it be the level of the StreamHandler()?
How can I check this after it has been set up?
>>> loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
>>> loggers
[<Logger log1 (DEBUG)>, <Logger log2 (DEBUG)>]


Your guess is right. The issue is caused by the fact that the logger has passed your message to a handler of level INFO.
You can check it out by running the following code:
for handler in log2.handlers:
    print(handler)
    
<StreamHandler <stderr> (INFO)>

You can "fix" this by looping over all the logging handlers and set a new level:
for handler in log2.handlers:
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

And you can see the updated level by doing this:
for handler in log2.handlers:
    print(handler)
    
<StreamHandler <stderr> (DEBUG)>

Now you are able to print debug statements as well:
log2.debug("why is this not showing")
20241007191611.264|DEBUG|<input>:1|why is this not showing


The problem is that you set a level for the handler at initialization time. By default, a handler is created with a level set to NOT_SET which allows to process any message passed from the logger.
But if you first set the handler level to INFO, it will never be able to process a DEBUG level message, unless you lower its level.
IMHO the simplest way is not to set the level:
    ...
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(file_fmt, datefmt))
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    ...

That way you will be able to safely change the logger level without having to care for the handler level.
